# Geopy - HTTP error 404: Not Found

Tags: python, geopy

I am using a `geopy` package to get address from Lon/Lat coordinates. The code looks as follows:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(scheme='http')
location = geolocator.reverse('43.4393,-3.7694', timeout=5)
print location.address
```

However at one point, the package stopped working and I am receiving following error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-2-e911deb2bb07>", line 2, in <module>
    location = geolocator.reverse('43.4393,-3.7694', timeout=5)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\osm.py", line 248, in reverse
    self._call_geocoder(url, timeout=timeout), exactly_one

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\base.py", line 160, in _call_geocoder
    raise GeocoderServiceError(message)

GeocoderServiceError: HTTP Error 404: Not found
```

Note that the opposite action - get lon/lat from address doesnt work either.

I could not find any information about the error either in the documentation or here. I will be happy for any suggestions. Thank you.

**EDIT**

I tried to reinstall the package, but no effect. Moreover, the code works on my colleague's PC. It really puzzles me.

**EDIT 2**

Ok, it started working after few hours. Love this kind of errors.

Comment: The same code works for me though. Maybe the http request you're trying to ping isn't responding back. Try Nominatim() without a scheme. Maybe that will work.

Comment: I must use the `scheme='http'` otherwise I am getting SSL error.

Comment: This code is working fine. try with https. and also try with more timeout. Hope it will work.